# Why are distance searches using App Engine's Search Api returning no matches even in a production app?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, full-text-search, geospatial, gae-search

I am trying to run a distance search to retrieve indexed locations near a given geopoint, but I always get zero matches even for a deployed version of the app. I tried to run the search through the App Engine Console as well, but still could not get any matches.

This is my index:
[image]

And these are query string and result:
[image]

Could someone please help me figure out what is going wrong?

Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Have you tried without the quotes?

Comment: Yeah, I tried without the quotes also. It looks like the search is failing when the indexed GeoPoint field has more than six decimal places. It is working fine for lower precision numbers. This is quite strange and has not even been documented anywhere!